# Are they the "same" CodeWars. My code doesn't pass all tests

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Conditions of the problem:
Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.

My function looks like this:

```
public static bool comp(int[] a, int[] b)
        {
            bool result = false;
            if (a == null || b == null)
                return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (Math.Sqrt(b[i]) == a[j])
                    {
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    result = false;
                }
                if (result == false) break;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

But this function doesn't pass all tests. Where is the error in my code? And what is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: `if(a == null && b == null)` -- technically that should return true? Or am I being too fickle :)

Comment: `Math.Sqrt(b[i]) == a[j]` - if `a` is -2, what is `b`, and then what is the square root of `b`?

Comment: The best way to solve this is to write test cases that cover the problem space, and then start debugging when you find one that fails.

Comment: Protip: `Math.Sqrt` is expensive. It's much cheaper to compare `b[i]` to `a[j] *a[j]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
```

You are looping in a for each value in b.  Then your code cannot handle when there are multiples of the same value.
i.e. b = {1,1,2,3,4}; a={1,2,3,4,5}
This will return true for your code, which is obviously incorrect.

Furthermore, this line is really bad:

```
if (Math.Sqrt(b[i]) == a[j])
```

So what to do?  It's rather simple.

1. count each array in a dictionary, but count them differently.

   1. When counting a, square it, and count the squared value.  dictionary key = a[i]*a[i];  dictionary value += 1;
   2. When counting b, count as is.  dictionary key = b;  dictionary value -= 1;
2. Verify that your dictionary is empty/0 filled.

In Java, this becomes:

```
Map<Long, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
for (int av : a)
{
    long av2 = ((long) av) * av;
    map.put(av2, map.getOrDefault(av2, 0) + 1);
}

for (int bv : b)
{
    map.put(bv, map.getOrDefault(bv, 0) - 1);
}

boolean isEqual = true;
for (long k : count.keySet())
{
    isEqual &= map.get(k) == 0;
}
```

Replace map for dictionary, and methods on map for methods on dictionary, and you have c# code.

Comment: I don't know java, but does long av2 = av * av;` actually avoid overflow? It looks like it would do the conversion to long only after the `int` multiplication overflows.

Comment: well the intent of having long there was to avoid overflow but haven't tested it.  it may require long av2 = ((long) av) * av... well chances are it probably does require it

Answer (score 0):

Note the last part of the description, `regardless of the order`. That suggests you can't assume the squared value is at the same index as its source. Sorting both arrays would be the first thing I'd try in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
            if (a == null || b == null)
                return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
```

So, you're testing that all values from b[] "match" at least one value in a[]. But are there any values in a[] that don't match any value in b[]? What if the array's are different lengths? Or have duplicate values?

```cs
Math.Sqrt(b[i])
```

Sqrt is slower than `a[i]^2`, plus the return value is a double which can't accurately represent all integers. Then what about negative values in a[]?

Comment: double _can_ represent all java integers. (double has a 52 or 53 bit significand, whereas java ints are 32 bits).

Comment: But does `Math.Sqrt` compute the answer to enough significant figures up to `Sqrt(int.MaxValue)`? I dunno. I still wouldn't bother, particularly when there is a simpler alternative that also handles `a<0`.